# SharePoint 2010 List Data Sheet Error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, datasheet

I have list with about 19.000 items. When I change the view to the DataSheetView, after a few minutes I'm gettin this error: " Cannot connect to the server at this time. You can continue working with this list but some data may not be available.". I searched net for this, found "net stop sens" command but I do not want to run this command on production server. What can I do except this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit on how many list items can be shown in a view. Contact your SharePoint administrator for details. 19,000 items certainly tops the out-of-the-box limits for any SharePoint list view, which is normally 5,000 items per view.

Talk to your administrator or explore alternatives to a list view, like exporting the data to Excel or Access for further processing.